# Conditional groupping in Python using groupby function on Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, group-by, pandas-groupby

I was coding for a project and I got stuck here. I have used `groupby` function before but not like this. My doubt is-

I have a dataframe as belows:

```
| ID | Side | Price |
| 1  | left | 100   |
| 2  | right| 90    |
| 3  | right| 50    |
| 2  | left | 70    |
| 3  | left | 110   |
```

I want to groupby the ID and then subtract the price for that ID. If the price of `left > right`, then the ID must be set as left and price should be `left_price - right_price` and similarly if `right > left`, the final price would be the same as `left_price - right_price`.

The output for above should be like:

```
| ID | Side | Price |
| 1  | left | 100   |
| 2  | right| 20    |
| 3  | left | -60   |
```

I am using python-2.7. Here is the code that I have written till now (or am trying to write)

```
id_group = df.sort_values(['ID','Side'])
id_group = df.groupby(['ID'])['Price'].diff().fillna(df['Price'])
```

Comment: (Not the downvoter) - This question is likely being downvoted because an effort to solve this on your own has not been shown. Please update the question to show your attempt(s) to work this out yourself.

Comment: Aside, as Python <= 3.5 (and soon to be 3.6) are now out of support, may I recommend upgrading (if possible) to the latest feature release of 3.8.

Comment: I know, but I cannot update it. It is work related.

Comment: I solved your problem but I guess your description is wrong . Your final result should be {1: ['left', 100], 2: ['right', 20], 3: ['left', 60]}, instead of {1: ['left', 100], 2: ['right', 20], 3: ['left', -60]}. Since you are subtracting lower from higher.

Comment: No the price has to follow same pattern. Like subtraction should happen from one side to other throughout. Not from Larger to smaller like in a normal case.

Comment: For that only I tried sorting with Side and then doing diff.

Comment: Oh sorry, then I posted a wrong answer. So in order to edit it can you explain what is the pattern of subtraction. Is it always left to right?

Comment: Yeah, the pattern could be anything if it is consistent. I have taken left - right throughout

Comment: Will we also sum all the lefts and rights? I mean will there be multiple lefts and rights?

Comment: No there is will only one left and only one right always

Comment: I've edited the answer now it substracts always previous to next, and if sides are the same it sums them up. If you don't want to sum them up you can just add "pass" instead of "calculated_price=Previous_Price+Price"

Comment: Okay, I will try to run it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```
Number_of_Ids=dict(DF["Id"].value_counts())
SideID_price={}
def Side_by_max(row):
    for row in DF.values:
        ID=row[0]
        Side=row[1]
        Price=row[2]
        if Number_of_Ids[ID]>1:
            if ID not in SideID_price.keys():
                SideID_price[ID]=[Side,Price]
            else:
                Previous_Side,Previous_Price=SideID_price[ID]
                if Previous_Side==Side:
                    calculated_price=Previous_Price+Price
                else:
                    calculated_price=Previous_Price-Price 
                SideID_price[ID]=[Side,calculated_price]

        else:
            SideID_price[ID]=[Side,Price]
```

Getting the dict:

```
Side_by_max(DF.values)
```

Reconstructing resulting DF:

```
Result=pd.DataFrame(SideID_price).T
Result.index.name = "ID"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more than one ID with the same side, I've introduced an additional data point (-see id:2) to your example in which case it will aggregate `{price}` if the composite key `{id, side}` are the same. Please find my solution below.

```
data = {'ID':[1,2,2,3,2,3], 
    'Side':['left', 'left','right', 'right','left', 'left'],
    'Price':[100,10,90,50,70,110]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
```

---

```
   ID   Side    Price
0   1   left    100
1   2   left    10
2   2   right   90
3   3   right   50
4   2   left    70
5   3   left    110
```

---

```
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(
           index='ID', 
           columns='Side', 
           values='Price', 
           aggfunc='sum', 
           fill_value=0)
df_pivot
```

---

```
Side left right
ID      
1   100   0
2   80    90
3   110   50
```

---

```
#**custom function** 
    def evaluate_side(row):
        if row['left'] > row['right']:
            return 'left', row['left']-row['right']
        else: 
            return 'right', row['left']-row['right']

#Results Table Only
result = df_pivot.apply(lambda x: evaluate_side(x), axis=1, result_type='expand')
result.rename(columns={0:'Result', 1:'Price'}, inplace=True)
print(result)
```

---

```
   Result  Price
ID              
1    left    100
2   right    -10
3    left     60
```

---

```
#Full Table with Original Values
df_pivot[result.columns] = result
print(df_pivot)
```

---

```
Side  left  right Result  Price
ID                             
1      100      0   left    100
2       80     90  right    -10
3      110     50   left     60
```